# Headphone front port not detecting in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, pulseaudio

In my Debian 10, headphone connection to the front port of the cpu not detecting. but it's detecting the port in the back of the cpu. in order to detect front port every time i have to connect it to the back port then change the port to 'Headphones' using pulseaudio volume control.[image]

The port option visible only after connecting the headphone to the back port, after every time debian boot's up.

is there any fix to this?